# Passing parameters to macro. Different results. Assembly

Tags: assembly, parameters, macros, masm, emu8086

The following macro returns value 17*y+x in register AX
But it gives different results when I call it:

```
nr 09h 03h

mov ah,09h
mov al,03h
nr ah al
```

The result should be the same but it is not. Why?

```
nr MACRO x, y 
push bx
push ax
xor ax,ax
xor bx,bx

mov al,y
mov bl, 17
mul bl     ;ax=17*y

mov bl,x

add ax,bx

pop bx
pop bx
ENDM
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike a function a macro just substitutes **text** in the source file just as you had written there.

```
nr ah al
```

inserts into the source:

```
push bx
push ax
xor ax,ax
xor bx,bx

mov al,al
mov bl, 17
mul bl     ;ax=17*y

mov bl,ah

add ax,bx

pop bx
pop bx
```

`mov al,al` and `mov bl,ah` are formed by the macro. The macro inserts just the text "ah" resp. "al", **not** the values of the registers. However, previously the instructions `xor ax,ax` and `xor bx,bx` had destroyed the former values of the registers. Also, `mul bl` destroys any former value of `AX`.